# Create multiple nested Child grids in Kendo UI Grid using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

can we implement multiple child nested grids in Kendo UI Grid using ASP.NET MVC i can implement 1 or 2 Child grids but how to implement 5-6 child grids inside one Parent kendo Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Country).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.City).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Title);

        })               
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))            
        )        
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(200);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(5)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
```

and sample or demo link will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want one grid inside another? Or are you referring to aggregating grids? http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/aggregates.html

Comment: No. i want multi level hierarchy, many child inside one Parent Grid.

Comment: Do you need something like this: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should follow the same approach. The only thing that you should bother is that each Grid should have unique name.

Check the following [demo](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/grid-ajax-hierarchy-editing), there are 3 levels of the hierarchy.

Comment: thanks. that shows 3 Level hierarchy. Can this be done a progmatical way? depending on the data grid should auto create nested grids?

Comment: No it is not possible, you should know the structure of the Children, it cannot be resolved dynamically